# How to add imageview to tableviewcell under label programmatically in swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview

How to add UIImageView to UITableViewCell programmatically under UIlabel text in swift, there maybe multiple imageViews..

[image]

Comment: what is your current approach? and what is wrong with it?

Comment: i try this but not working
var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: cell.text_lbl.frame.origin.x, y: cell.frame.size.height + 10, width: 20, height: 20))
        cell.contentView.addSubview(imageView)